# Keycloak spring boot adapter does not check Authorization header for valid access token

Tags: spring-security, keycloak

when I send a valid request from postman to **spring boot** app that integrated with **Keycloak**, It works perfect and send 200 seccess code. If I send the request without **Authorization bearer** header for second time, It send 200 success code again. However, It must send 401 error code. In fact, until the token is valid, resource server does not check Authorization header. I encounter this bug when I use **spring security config class**.